# Client-Server Multi-Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, client

I am having a problem implementing a simple multi threaded server in Java.

My idea is for a server to broadcast a message to all clients(without the use of a multicast).

For this I am implementing a broadcast method. This method will use a for loop, and loop through each client Thread, which I have stored in a collection. It will call each threads send(), which outputs writeUTF().

My problem is for 2 clients A+B.

A outputs: hello
B outputs: hi there

B will not recieve hello, and when B type again, it will the recieve A's message.Code example:

```
import java.net.*;
```

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ServerThreadHandler extends Thread {

```
private AuctionServer       server          = null;
private Socket              socket          = null;
private String              name            = null;
private int                 ID              = -1;       
private DataInputStream     dataIn          = null;
public  DataOutputStream    dataOut         = null;
private Thread              thread;


protected static Vector handlers = new Vector();

// reason server is used here is because ian was calling a server method broadcast
// from inside the 
public ServerThreadHandler(AuctionServer server, Socket socket, String name) throws IOException{
    this.server = server;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.name   = name;

    dataIn = new DataInputStream( new
                            BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

    dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());       
}



// handles a specific client.
public void run(){

    System.out.println("Server running.."); 

    while(true){
        try{
            // broadcast to all clients. This will only be one client in this case.
            server.broadcast(dataIn.readUTF());

            int pause = (int)(Math.random() * 3000);
            Thread.sleep(pause);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public void send(String msg){
    try{
        dataOut.writeUTF(msg);
        dataOut.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e){

    }
}
```

Server code:

```
// broadcast this to clients.
public void broadcast(String msg){
        for(int i = 0; i < clientCount; i++){
            clients[i].send(msg);       
        }
}
```

Where clients[] is

```
private ServerThreadHandler clients[] = new ServerThreadHandler[3];
```

Comment: Why don't you give us an example of what you've written so far, and tell us where it's crashing.

Comment: Sure, to clarify I have gotten the server to accept multiple clients, but now the broadcast is not to each client, only to one. And example is in the code above.

Comment: You haven't provided any code...

Comment: Ok, I have tried to edit the post to provide code but have been getting errors each time. I will continue to try so bear with me if you would. I have also updated the problem question.

Comment: You are creating a thread inside the run of another thread (???), but never starting it. This is very confusing...

Comment: Ah this, is an mistake, i have removed it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you a rough outline, you can fill in the rest of the details:

```
public class Server {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private List<Socket> clientSockets;

    // constructor(s)

    private class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        public ThreadTask(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() { 
             while(true) {      
                // read message from clientSocket
                for(Socket peerSocket: clientSockets) {
                    // send message on peerSocket
                }
             }
        }

    }

    private void acceptConnections() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientSockets.add(clientSocket);
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadTask(clientSocket));
                t.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {               
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```